# Rogue Admin. How to gain control of unauthorized page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have recently been awarded the contract for an organization's web presence. They have an existing Facebook page. The previous admin refuses to relinquish control, however.

How do I go about "seizing" this page?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's necessarily a technological answer to this so much as a business/legal one- it will probably be up to the organization to address the issue- just like they'd have to give you the keys to your office if you took over for someone who had been fired

Comment: do you have the username and password? If so then lock them out. If you don't, then go back to the site owner.

Comment: I see your comment in the answer below, you say the issue was resolved through legal channels. It would really be helpful of you to share the details for the sake of other users who might find themselves in the same predicament.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook makes it easy to report someone for impersonating a person, but the procedure isn't clear for cases like yours.
If the previous admin is no longer associated with the company, then it is the case of impersonating your business.  You can report the page for trademark/copyright infringement since it has used your company name, logo and identifiable information.
The link to report such violations is http://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=208282075858952

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone!  This issue was resolved through legal channels.

Comment: What legal channels did you use?